# Can TIME_WAIT port be reused for different remote server?

Tags: centos, tcp

On a machine, I found there are many TIME_WAIT connections(to different remote server) using same local port by `netstat`:

```
tcp        0      0 10.32.198.120:10240         10.32.92.81:4000            TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 10.32.198.120:10240         10.66.32.192:80             TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 10.32.198.120:10242         10.32.92.81:4000            TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 10.32.198.120:10242         10.66.32.192:80             TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 10.32.198.120:10243         10.32.92.81:4000            TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 10.32.198.120:10243         10.66.32.192:80             TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 10.32.198.120:10244         10.32.92.81:4000            TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 10.32.198.120:10244         10.66.32.192:80             TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 10.32.198.120:10245         10.66.32.192:80             TIME_WAIT
```

I knew TIME_WAIT is designed for preventing old packets from a previous connection from being accepted into a new connection. But since a new connection to a different remote server will not be mistaken as the old connection, so I think it's clearly safe to use a TIME_WAIT port for a different remote server.

So, is what I saw (same local ports in different connections) an evidence that TIME_WAIT port is reused?

I am on CentOS 6.5 (tcp_tw_reuse is set as 0) and these connections are created by python2.7.6/requests2.12.1.

Answer (score 5):

The fact that your sockets are in TIME_WAIT doesn't *really* matter here, they could be in ESTABLISHED state and your question would still stand - **why am I seeing the same source port for multiple connections**?

**TLDR**: As long as the TCP 4-tuple (Source IP, Source Port, Destination IP, Destination Port) is not the same, it is permitted to use the same source port for multiple connections.

TIME-WAIT is used to prevent old packets from being accepted in a new connection using the **exact same** TCP 4-tuple as an old connection.

---

In most cases, Linux automatically assigns the source port from the Ephemeral port range which defaults to 32768 to 61000:

```
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
32768   60999
```

When deciding on which source port to use, the Kernel will first of all check if there is any source port which is unused from the ephemeral port range. With ~28k possible source ports, the Kernel is normally able to find an available port and stop there. If all 28k ports are in use however, it will next check if any of the ports pass the `check_established` [source](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/1bbdceef1e535add893bf71d7b7ab102e4eb69eb/net/ipv4/inet_hashtables.c#L520) function which will allow an already allocated source port to be re-used as long as the new connection is for a different TCP 4-tuple.

Also, rather than letting the Kernel automatically assign a source port, it is also possible to programatically tell the Kernel exactly which source IP and port you would like to use for a specific connection.